# Is there a way to add a new column based on a value of a single row without a loop?

Tags: r, tidyverse

In the below dataset, if `Loc==1`, I want to calculate a value, but if `Loc!=1`, I want to calculate a value *based on the value I calculated in the first condition* (the value calculated at `Loc==1`). I know I can accomplish this in a loop, but I'm trying to avoid loops if I can help it. It should look something like this, note that the `first` object doesn't actually exist, it's just a placeholder to better explain what I'm looking for.

```
data2 <- data %>%
  mutate(Residual = ifelse(Loc==1,
                           pmin(XD_VD+SE, val), # first calc
                           pmin(first + SE, val))) # second calc based on first calc
```

If there *is* a way to do it without using a loop, can anyone think of one? Here's a snippet of my data:

```
structure(list(Loc = 1:5, val = c(29, 49, 44, 50, 37), XD = c(66.12, 
66.12, 66.12, 66.12, 66.12), VD = c(30.1780172853143, 30.1780172853143, 
30.1780172853143, 30.1780172853143, 30.1780172853143), XD_VD = c(35.9419827146857, 
35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857, 35.9419827146857
), SE = c(0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77, 0.77)), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You should show what you have tried and the results. One possible error is using quotes around the numeric value since “1” is not == to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this in two steps like so:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)

data %>%
  mutate(
    Residual = pmin(XD_VD + SE, val),
    Residual = ifelse(Loc == 1,
      Residual,
      pmin(Residual[Loc == 1] + SE, val)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>     Loc   val    XD    VD XD_VD    SE Residual
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1    29  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29  
#> 2     2    49  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29.8
#> 3     3    44  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29.8
#> 4     4    50  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29.8
#> 5     5    37  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29.8
```

**EDIT** After the clarification in the comment, one option would be to use `purrr::accumulate2`:

```r
library(dplyr, warn = FALSE)
library(purrr)

data %>%
  mutate(
    Residual = purrr::accumulate2(SE, val,
      \(x, y, z) {
        min(x + y, z)
      },
      .init = XD_VD[Loc == 1]
    )[-1]
  )
#> # A tibble: 5 × 7
#>     Loc   val    XD    VD XD_VD    SE Residual
#>   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#> 1     1    29  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29  
#> 2     2    49  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     29.8
#> 3     3    44  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     30.5
#> 4     4    50  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     31.3
#> 5     5    37  66.1  30.2  35.9  0.77     32.1
```

Comment: This is great! Except I realized I improperly explained what I needed. I am trying to base the second Residual value based on the former calculation, not just at `Loc==1`. What I actually need is pmin at Loc1, then pmin at Loc1 + SE, val, then pmin at Loc2 + SE, val ... does that make sense? I tried to use `lag(Residual, 1)`, but the numbers don't look right. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I accepted the answer, tho, since you actually did answer my original question, ha!

Comment: `lag` will not work. I just made an edit which should work.

Comment: Fantastic, that's EXACTLY what I was looking for. That `accumulate2()` function is amazing, but I'm not entirely sure what it's doing. Is `SE` the `x` argument, `val` the `y` argument, and `XD_VD` the `z` argument of the function? Or is the `y` argument the `XD_VD` and the `z` argument is `val`?

Comment: :D It is. Nop. `x` is the accumulated value which I `.init`alize with the `XD_VD` value for Loc 1, i.e. you can think of it as `first`. The SE value is y and val is z. Then we loop over the pairs of SE and val taking in to account the x value from the previous step. Finally, the first element in the resulting vector contains the `.init` value. Hence I use [-1] to drop it.

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you sooooo much for showing me how to do it and explaining it, I'm so excited about this function.